# Why is a specific question with a certain answer marked as opinion-based?

Tags: support, moderation

Can someone explain to me why the question [Can the use of OPKG on ZyXEL Keenetic Ultra II cause damage to the firmware or its incorrect operation?](https://superuser.com/questions/1715044/can-the-use-of-opkg-on-zyxel-keenetic-ultra-ii-cause-damage-to-the-firmware-or-i) is opinion-based?

I really don't understand people who think that questions about vulnerability (security and stability issues) are based on opinion. As if, there is a vulnerability or not, depends on my (or another) opinion. If this were really the case, I would be the master of reality and certainly not ask questions to other people.

I am very surprised that such obvious things are not obvious to people capable of closing questions. I'd really like to know **why do they think that my question is opinion-based?**

P.S.
It would be very ironic if this question on Meta was closed with the note *opinion-based*.

*UPD:*

And this question still remains relevant. I, like other Q&A participants, still do not understand what needs to be improved in the question.
I do not know what needs to be improved and I am editing the structure of the question so that it is certainly clearer to anyone that it is not based on opinion.

At the same time, others who also do not know what to improve, see that nothing has changed in the very essence and do not open a question marked "the original close reason is not solved". **A vicious circle.**

Maybe the moderators can finally solve this? They're here for some reason, aren't they?

Comment: I very strongly agree with this, in fact I literally came to ask this very question and saw it was the first question at the top of the page.  However, in my case, I didn't even have multiple inquiries; there was one question, which had only one possible correct answer.  I believe SE needs to modify their language used in regards to this closure reason, or address why mods are selecting this option when closing posts for reasons that don't actually pertain to the one selected and shown.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that is opinion-based, however I do think it's asking too many questions. If you could narrow the question down a bit, you may be able to get it re-opened. For example, if you ask if the package manager can brick the router, that would be easier to answer.

Comment: But after all, all the sub-questions I asked are related. I want to know the answer to each of them, since what the package manager won't break can be broken using iptables (for example). If I ask these questions separately, I'm sure I'll get **[dupliсate]**.

Comment: @AlexA. Try asking just one at a time, and make sure each question is precise and specific.

Comment: Most StackExchange Q&A don't prohibit sub-questions. The sub-questions are answered because people understand that once they are asked, then the answer to them interests the author of the question. It seems to me rather strange to close a question because of sub-questions. Moreover, the sub-questions clarify what exactly the author is concerned about. For example, I am concerned about any way of harming the firmware, configuration and functioning of the router as a whole. If I ask only one of the subqueries, it will not cover the entire area of interest.

Comment: @AlexA. I'm just giving suggestions for what I think would keep the question open. I personally think your question is fine.